# sorting based on groups in pandas series

Tags: python, sorting, pandas

I would like to order a series (multilevel) in descending order of values  (per group).
For instance for the following series with two levels (id, company).

```
id         company     
86246      10000        841.90        
           10930090      28.44  
           10948797      52.69      
126082871  1076172070     9.99  
           1076211171     4.99  
           1076317676     7.99  
           1078616272     5.00
```

Is there any way of sorting (descending) for each group so that I get as follows ?

```
id          company
86246       10000        841.90
            10948797      52.69
            10930090      28.44
126082871   1076172070     9.99
            1076317676     7.99
            1078616272     5.00
            1076211171     4.99
```

Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how your multi-level indexed DataFrame was generated, but assuming you have a flat DataFrame `df`

```
>>> df
          id     company   value
0      86246       10000  841.90
1      86246    10930090   28.44
2      86246    10948797   52.69
3  126082871  1076172070    9.99
4  126082871  1076211171    4.99
5  126082871  1076317676    7.99
6  126082871  1078616272    5.00
```

you can simply sort by the column `value` and create a multi-level index using `set_index()`:

```
>>> df.sort_index(by='value', ascending=False).set_index(['id', 'company'])
                       value
id        company           
86246     10000       841.90
          10948797     52.69
          10930090     28.44
126082871 1076172070    9.99
          1076317676    7.99
          1078616272    5.00
          1076211171    4.99
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `s.order(ascending=False)` might work, where s is the variable holding the series.